# Iterate over JavaScript URL Object's Properties

Tags: javascript, w3c

I'm trying to map an instance of JavaScript's [URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to a plain object and can't understand why it's not working.

I'm guessing this is because the properties are not enumerable, but it's not clear to me why this would be the case.

```js
let input = 'https://www.google.com/index.html?bar=baz#foo'

let url = new URL(input)

console.log(url.origin)
console.log(url.protocol)
console.log(url.host)
console.log(url.pathname)
console.log(url.hash)
console.log(url.search)

let urlMap = Object.entries(url).reduce((map, [key, value]) => {
  map[key] = value
  return map
}, {})


console.log(urlMap)  // returns {}
```

Is this something I can do?  My goal was to compose the url properties like this:

```
return { ...url, pathname: alteredPathname }
```

Comment: `url.hasOwnProperty('origin') === false`, for example - they're getters, not plain properties

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe.  I see that `url[key]` is working with the getters, so I will need to use that I guess.

Comment: Do you actually need a plain object? An `URL` instance would be easier to deal with.

Comment: @Bergi that's a fine question.  As I mentioned I was hoping to compose the url's properties with additional ones with a spread, but maybe I should just set the properties instead.

Comment: @MattMorgan Yes, plain assignments sound much simpler. And you can get back the URL as a string in the end. You could even do `Object.assign(new URL(input), {pathName: alteredPathname}).toString()` if you are looking for object notation.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the _proto of url instance you will see, those fields are getters and setters. Therefor Object.entries / keys won't work here

[image]

Howeve loop below should work

```
const input = 'https://www.google.com/index.html?bar=baz#foo'

const url = new URL(input)
const map = {};
for (let key in url) {
  map[key] = url[key]
}

console.log(map);
```

Here is the output
[image: Here is the output]

Comment: It actually works. Just tried on Chrome and attached a screenshot to my post

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Weird, it didn't work when I tried converting it to a snippet.  Maybe I fat-fingered it.